# Devise Giving Admin Privileges to Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, admin

Just added an Admin model to Devise. I am on Rails 4.

I would like to give the Admin privileges to destroy and update articles that other users have created.

Having trouble finding documentation on how to do so.

Right now I have this on my index page, which allows the current creator to destroy/edit:

```
<% if current_user == article.user %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </p>
<%end%>
```

Would I add something here to let admins be able to do this as well?

Also here is my destroy action in articles_controller:

```
def destroy
  @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

Thank you for all of your help! Still a rails newbie. Tons to learn. If this is already documented somewhere could you please point me in that direction. Thanks!

Comment: Don't confuse authorisation with authentication. Two different things. For authorisation, look at Pundit. https://github.com/elabs/pundit

Comment: How do you identify who is an admin or not? Are you using a Gem, or are you adding the information to your `User` model?

Comment: I created a separate model for the Admin, and created an admin with the rails console. There is no way for an admin to sign up, just login, hence creating inside of the rails c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Quite an extensive documentation:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md

Very first steps are to simply add

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!
```

to your controllers.

If you also need authorization have a look at cancan:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Or rather https://github.com/elabs/pundit since CanCan is no longer maintained.

Comment: Cancan is no longer maintained. It's abandoned. Look into something like Pundit. https://github.com/elabs/pundit

Comment: @Mohamad CanCan has a continuation called [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), although in practice, people still refer to it as CanCan.

Comment: decided to go role based instead of a separate model and use cancancan, thanks everyone!